# Regex validation results

Tags: c#, regex, validation

In a web form, I have a TextBox object with a RegularExpressionValidator. My problem is that when the textBox is empty, the validator returns that my string(an empty string) is valid, but when I want to check this again using a Regex object from code with the same expression, the result is that the empty string did not matches with the expression. Why does this happen?

Here is my code:

ASPX:

```
<table style="background-color:#eeeeee; padding:10">
          <tr valign="top">
             <td colspan="3">
                <asp:Label ID="lblOutput" 
                     Text="Enter a 5-digit ZIP Code" 
                     runat="server"
                     AssociatedControlID="TextBox1"/>
             </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
             <td colspan="3">
                <b>Personal Information</b>
             </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td align="right">
                Zip Code:
             </td>
             <td>
                <asp:TextBox id="TextBox1" 
                     runat="server"/>
             </td>
             <td>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="RegularExpressionValidator1" 
                     ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
                     ValidationExpression="^\d\d*$"
                     Display="Static"
                     ErrorMessage="ZIP code must be 5 numeric digits"
                     EnableClientScript="False" 
                     runat="server"/>
             </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
             <td></td>
             <td>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" text="Validate" 
                     OnClick="ValidateBtn_Click" 
                     runat="server" />
             </td>
             <td></td>
          </tr>
       </table>
```

C#:

```
protected void ValidateBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            RegularExpressionValidator minValidator = (RegularExpressionValidator)FindControl("RegularExpressionValidator1");
            minValidator.Validate();
            if (!minValidator.IsValid)
            {
                lblOutput.Text = "Page is InValid.";
            }
            else
            {
                lblOutput.Text = "Page is Valid.";
            }
            String exp = @"^\d\d*$";
            Regex r = new Regex(exp);
            if (r.IsMatch(TextBox1.Text))
            {
                Response.Write("strings matches");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("strings does not matches");
            }

        }
```

And here is a screenshot with the page:

[image]

Comment: The regular expression validator does not get invalidated by empty strings. You'll either need to take that into account in the reg ex or make a required validation as well

Comment: But I don't understand, if the validator does not validate an empty string, why does it return that the empty string matches with my regex if it does not even make the validation?

Comment: @Buda Gavril why you check RegularExpressionValidator on client side as well as server side?

Comment: Your RegEx requires the string to have content, the RegEx Validator does not. Therefore the page is valid, but the content "differs" because your regex does not "match"

Comment: please change the flash to "strings do not match" it is irritating me.

Comment: so even if I change my regex to have at least 5 characters, the validator will still return true with en empty string?

Comment: @BudaGavril Yes, if you check remarks at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx you would see `Validation succeeds if the input control is empty. If a value is required for the associated input control, use a RequiredFieldValidator control in addition to the RegularExpressionValidator control.`

Comment: I was hoping not to go there because there is an user control with many grids containing other hrods with textBoxes and their validators and I was hoping that I would not have to make major changes in the code... but thanks anyway